# Is there a way to force artifactory jenkins plugin to store in a hierarchal way?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I have a jenkins server and artifactory connection. I want to use the artifactory jenkins plugin to send out files in a hierarchal way .

E.g a rpm might go as sys/arch/os/packages/rpm. IS there a way to force artifactory jenkins plugin to use this hierarchy globally for every job as soon as it sees that it is a rpm while uploading stuff to artifactory or make a custom structure.

Comment: Of course you could. Not sure why plugin did you use, In our jenkins, there is a config for artifact plugin called publish Artifacts, inside this attribute, you can define how the structure looks like. for example: deploy/*=>com/tt/cc/productname/

Comment: Our artifact plugin config is located in the Jenkins job page, and Build Environment Block -- > Generic-Artifactory Integration

Comment: @Tim - I Don't think I explained it very well, please check my edit now.

Comment: I am still not 100% sure I understand your question, but at least I dont find a global config for this. One way is that you can create a separate Jenkins job to do the artifact upload work, inside this job you could copy the artifcact such as rpm from other jobs, then upload it into artifactory.  For different project, you can distinguish them by parameters. Hope this will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim's answer in the comments is accurate. You can configure the deployment of artifacts after the build by using the [Artifactory Generic (Freestyle) Integration](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringGeneric%28Freestyle%29Builds).
It is configured on a job level.

You can take a look on [a bunch of job templating and generating plugins and tools for job creation automation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins), the Artifactory deployment configuration is just a piece of xml in the job config file.

If you want to verify that the files are uploaded in the correct layout, you can use [a user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins).

Comment: Well, I ended up writing my own plugin which overrides the generic artifactory plugin with my own custom rules.